# Odd SIGSEGV when trying to access public variable from its own class

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program using OpenGL, but I've come across a problem. I have a class called "Quad" and the two variables causing the problem are a public map and a public Vector3 (which is another class). Here are those two variables defined in Quad.h:

```
std::map<unsigned int, Vector3*> vertexes;
Vector3* normal;
```

"normal" is initiated (I think that's the word) in the Quad constructor, like this:

```
normal = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

The map is just added to like this:

```
vertexes[0] = &vertex;
```

`vertex` being a plain Vector3, and the map accepts pointers to Vector3's so I had to reference it like that.

I can print out the correct value of Vector3 through another function but for some reason I get a segmentation fault in this:

```
void Quad::draw()
{
    glNormal3f(normal->x, normal->y, normal->z);

    for (std::map<unsigned int, Vector3*>::iterator i = this->vertexes.begin(); i !=   this->vertexes.end(); ++i) {
        glVertex3f(i->second->x, i->second->y, i->second->z);
    }
}
```

I know it's caused by the public variable because the fault would not happen if I comment out the contents of the method. `cout << normal->x << endl;` also causes a fault, wheras `cout << "Hello World!" << endl;` does not. But what is the difference between this function and this;

```
void Quad::calculateNormal()
{
    Vector3 tmp = *vertexes[0];
    tmp = tmp.getFaceNormal(*vertexes[1], *vertexes[2]);
    normal = &tmp;
    std::cout << *normal << std::endl;
}
```

This is where normal is redefined and printed. Even replacing `std::cout << *normal << std::endl;` with `std::cout << normal->x << std::endl;` works and gives me correct data, but not in the other function? I just don't understand. I'm pretty sure it's something stupid (I hope so). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you were looking for the word initialized, not initiated. No offence meant.

Comment: what is the scope of `vertex`? Does it live as long as or longer than `vetrices`?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the question. What is working, and what is not working?  The descriptions of the errors are difficult to understand.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `std::map` instead of the more common `std::vector`?

Comment: @batbrat: Ah, that was the word. I always get confused between them both. Thank you. @juanchopanza: Looks like you're on to something, as well as Jochaim. `vertex` does not last as long as vertexes, I completely forgot the idea that pointers actually point to the variable and when it goes out of scope, I can't access the value any more. I would have to somehow make `vertex` last as long as the map it's in, right? Not sure how to do that. Would I start having to pass the actual value in rather than a pointer to the value? Sorry about everything being rushed, by the way, I am in a rush

Answer (score 4):

If you have code similar to this:

```
// Global map of vertices
std::map<unsigned int, Vector3*> vertexes;

void foo()
{
    Vector3 vertex;
    vertexes[0] = &vertex;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    std::cout << vertexes[0]->x << '\n';
}
```

Then you are invoking *undefined behavior*. This is because the pointer you add in function `foo` is no longer valid, as it points to a local variable.

Comment: `vertexes` is an `std::map` though.

Comment: @juanchopanza Oops, modified my answer to help with the probable cause.

Comment: This is exactly my situation. I now realise that the pointers contained in `vertexes` are pointing to values that have gone out of scope. But how do I go abouts solving this short of making the map use plain `Vector3`'s as opposed to pointers to them? - Thanks

Comment: @Jishaxe How about using the `new` operator: `Vector3 *vertex = new Vector3;`?

Comment: I have attempted to use this: `tmp.vertexes[0] = new Vector3(x, y, z);` but I still have the same crash. Am I not doing it right, or maybe the probem resides somewhere else? Also, the problem with the `normal` was fixed simply by accepting the value instead of a pointer to the value, as anticipated but I don't want to do that for the map just yet as there is a lot of code depending on it being a list of _pointers_